# Deleting underscores at the end of string Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string array

```
Str_in = {'ab_cd_a9_b5__','ab_cd_r_','ef_g','3swe_4r_2345___','swe','eds______'};
```

how to delete the trailing underscores in the above string array. The length of each string is not constant and the n umber of underscores may vary. The expected output string is

```
Str_out = {'abcda9_b5','ab_cd_r','ef_g','3swe_4r_2345','swe','eds'};
```

Would any one help on this issue?

Comment: If you always expect the first part of the string to have the same length, you can simply take those characters. For example, `Str_out = cellfun(@(x) x(1:5), Str_in, 'UniformOutput', false)`

Comment: yes the number of underscore may vary. please check the edited question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's convenient to use regex to replace these characters. The pattern of trailing _ is (number of '_' is greater than or equals 1):

```
_+$
```

So the code is:

```
Str_in = {'ab_cd_a9_b5__','ab_cd_r_','ef_g','3swe_4r_2345___','swe','eds______'};    

Str_out = cellfun(@(x) regexprep(x, '_+$', ''), Str_in, 'UniformOutput', false);

% or do as Shai mentioned, 
Str_out = regexprep(Str_in, '_+$', '');

disp(Str_out);
```

Output:

```
  'ab_cd_a9_b5'    'ab_cd_r'    'ef_g'    '3swe_4r_2345'    'swe'    'eds'
```

Comment: `regexprep` can take a cell array of strings as input. no need for `cellfun` here: `Str_out = regexprep( Str_in, '_+$', '' )` will do the trick.